# Eclipse JDT AST: Problems parsing a class with nested members

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I would like to do some static code analysis for Java source code. For parsing I use the Eclipse JDT (3.6) `ASTParser` outside of Eclipse with following code:

```
private static final Map<String, String> COMPILER_OPTIONS;

static {
    COMPILER_OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, String>(JavaCore.getOptions());
    COMPILER_OPTIONS.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
    COMPILER_OPTIONS.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
    COMPILER_OPTIONS.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
}

private CompilationUnit parseReadSourceFileIfPossible(String readSourceFile) {
    CompilationUnit result = null;
    if (isPossibleToParse(readSourceFile)) {
        final ASTParser parser = createAndConfigureParser();
        parser.setSource(readSourceFile.toCharArray());
        result = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    }
    return result;
}

private ASTParser createAndConfigureParser() {
    final ASTParser result = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    result.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    result.setCompilerOptions(COMPILER_OPTIONS); return result;
}
```

For "normal" Java classes this approach works perfectly fine. However if I
parse the following class (`ValidUnrestrictedComponent`), the parser runs
into problems.

```
package valid;

import de.htwg_konstanz.joi.annotations.JoiComponten;

@JoiComponent
public final class ValidUnrestrictedComponent {

    private static final class Implementation implements TestInterface {

        @Override
        public int doSomething() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private ValidUnrestrictedComponent() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static Implementation getInstance() {
        return new Implementation();
    }

    private static void getNothing() {
      // Nothing to do here
    }

    private void doNothing() {
      // Nothing to do here
    }

}
```

I do receive an object of type `CompilationUnit`, however it does only contain the
nested member `Implementation` and its method. The rest of the class – like
`getInstance` or `doNothing` is missing.

The obtained `CompilationUnit` contains a field `problems` with the following
three problems:

- DefaultProblem (id=141): Pb(240) Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
- DefaultProblem (id=143): Pb(240) Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
- DefaultProblem (id=164): Pb(240) Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

I can not see any syntax errors in the above mentioned class
`ValidUnrestrictedComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you double check the contents of 'readSourceFile'? My guess is that there are no '\n' or new line characters in that. Missing new-line characters would result in all the lines after the first comment becoming part of the comment itself.

Comment: Thank you Deepak Azad! It was the missing line separators.